# XQuery / XPath: How to retrieve an attribute value from an ancestor node when using "|" operator?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I'm applying an XQuery file to two XML files:

-file1/snippet1-

```
<entry xml:id="SCHOM-2">
    <form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="cu">
        <orth>абиѥ</orth>
    </form>
    <form type="lemma" xml:lang="cu">
        <orth>абиѥ</orth>
        <cit type="counterpart" xml:lang="grc">
            <form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="grc">
                <orth>παραχρῆμα</orth>
            </form>
            <form type="lemma" xml:lang="grc">
                <orth>παραχρῆμα</orth>
            </form>
        </cit>
    </form>
</entry>
```

and
-file2/snippet2-

```
<entry xml:id="arg-3150">
    <form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="grc">
        <orth>ἐξαυτῆς</orth>
    </form>
    <form type="lemma" xml:lang="grc">
        <orth>ἐξαυτῆς</orth>
        <cit type="translation" xml:lang="cu">
            <form type="hyperlemma" xml:lang="cu">
                <orth>абиѥ</orth>
            </form>
            <form type="lemma" xml:lang="cu">
                <orth>абие</orth>
            </form>
        </cit>
    </form>
</entry>
```

Both snippets have the same structure. If I look for "абиѥ" within any `<form type="hyperlemma">` the path for snippet1 is `$file//entry/form[@type='hyperlemma']/orth` (path1), whereas for snippet2 it is `$file//entry/form/cit/form[@type='hyperlemma']/orth` (path2).

In the XQuery file, I have the following FLWOR expression:

```
xquery version "3.0";
...
for $file in collection($collection_path),
    $path_to_hyperlemma in $file//(entry | cit)/form[@type='hyperlemma']/orth [ft:query(., $searchphrase)]
let $entry_number := $path_to_hyperlemma/../../@xml:id
return
....
```

`$entry_number` is supposed to store the attribute value of `<entry xml:id="">`. But the way I'm doing it (using `/../../`) only returns, of course, the attribute value for `$file//entry/form[@type='hyperlemma']/orth`.

Is it possible to store the attribute value in `$entry_number`, regardless of whether it is path1 or path2?

Another question: I know that the use of `//` is not ideal performance wise. But if I replace `//` with the absolute path, I don't seem to be able to refer to node-sets on different levels. Is it at all possible to set the absolute path in this case?

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is here, can you show a small sample of the XML you're querying against?

Comment: @IanRoberts: I added two XML snippets and rephrased my question. I hope it's getting clearer now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rewriting may help:

```
for $file in collection($collection_path),
    $path_to_hyperlemma in $file/(descendant::entry | descendant::cit)/
       form[@type='hyperlemma']/orth[ft:query(., $searchphrase)]
let $entry_number := $path_to_hyperlemma/ancestor::*/@xml:id
return ...
```

- The `xml:id` attribute is resolved for all ancestors. This only works if there is just one ancestor with such an attribute. If there may be more, you'll either need use to select one of them (e.g. with `[position() = 1]` or `[position() = last()]`) or give us some clarification in your question on the document structure.
- The `descendant-or-self` step has been removed by using `descendant` steps within the parenthesis. However, please note that `//` may be optimized by the XQuery processor anyway (if possible, check out the resulting query plan)

Comment: Great! Both of your suggestions work perfectly. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2):

```
let $entry_number := $path_to_hyperlemma/ancestor::entry[1]/@xml:id
```

would look up the tree for the `xml:id` of the nearest ancestor element named `entry`.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks for having a second look at my question.